# Typing in one UITextField results in not being able to type in any other UITextField with a UIViewController, UIScrollView and AutoLayouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, autolayout

I have a simple application with a view controller consisting off `3 UITextFields`, a `DatePicker` and a `Segment` `Control`.

I have spent a ton of time getting my `ViewController` scrollable with AutoLayout and a `UIScrollView` (entirely in `Storyboard`). The problem I'm getting now though is when I start typing in any one of the UITextFields, I'm suddenly not able to type in any of the other text fields, though I can dismiss the keyboard, select dates in the `DatePicker` and select segments in the Segment Control.

This was of course not the case before implementing the scroll view and this is only occurring on the actual device rather than in the simulator (emphasising the importance of testing on a device).

I have read through a few SO answers but none of them seem to work.

Please see a screenshot of how my views are set up:

[image]

I've also gone onto the UIScrollView and ensured the following three are unticked:

[image]

I've enabled and disabled each of them individually but with no luck.

It took a ton of time to get the `AutoLayouts` working so I honestly hope I won't have to adjust too much here.

My thinking is that because I'm trying to click on a `textField`, perhaps the View is treating that as I'm wanting to scroll also. Though of course, when I first invoke this view controller, I can click on the 1st, 2nd or 3rd `TextField` while scrolling, so that makes sense no sense.

One SO question said it was a bug during the iOS 7 beta phases, but my device is running iOS 7.0.4.

My scrollview doesn't have an outlet because this entire procedure was done using Storyboards, but I'm happy to create one if need be.

Reading the Apple docs, it looks like `delaysContentTouches` is exactly what's required here, but that's turned off in my `UIScrollVIew`.

Basically any suggestions or assistance with this would be massively appreciated - it's driving me mad!